# How to show an image on a table in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to show an image (of a snake) on my Android application, that can appear **on** the board table (which is a `tablelayout`). How can I do this rather than the image being shown simply **above** the table?

[image]

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout table;
    ImageView image;
    private static final int TABLE_WIDTH = 12;
    private static final int TABLE_HEIGHT = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_root);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        // Populate the table with stuff
        for (int y = 0; y < TABLE_HEIGHT; y++) {
            final int row = y;
            TableRow r = new TableRow(this);
            table.addView(r);

            for (int x = 0; x < TABLE_WIDTH; x++) {
                final int col = x;
                Button b = new Button(this);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
//                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked (" + row + "," + col + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tooth cavity in 6 month\n (previously in 2 years)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        t.show();
                        if(row==0 && col==0){
                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.snake);
                        }
                        else{
                            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                });
                r.addView(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `FrameLayout` with a `TableLayout` and a `ImageView` in it. Due to FrameLayouts have the ability of overlapping things, making the background of the imageview transparent and drawing the snake on it would work.